# Hibernate Criteria query doesn't give the complete result

Tags: hibernate

```
Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria().addOrder(Order.asc("dtname"));
ProjectionList projection = Projections.projectionList();
projection.add(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("dtncode")));
projection.add(Projections.property("dtname"));
criteria.setProjection(projection);
List<VillageMaster> villageMasters = (List<VillageMaster>) 
criteria.list();
```

I have written above code but code not giving the exact result.
Anyone please help me to resolve issue. Sql query is generated is as below:

```
select distinct this.dtncode as y0, this.dtname11 as y1 
from village_master this
order by this.dtname11 asc
```

Comment: What result are you expecting and what result do you receive?

Comment: I am getting only distinct records 'dtncode' but i wanna both columns 'dtncode' and 'dtname'.

Comment: On your third line you've specified `Projections.distinct` for "dtncode".

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria().addOrder(Order.asc("dtname"));    
ProjectionList projection = Projections.projectionList();
projection.add(Projections.property("dtncode"));
projection.add(Projections.property("dtname"));
criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(projection));
List<VillageMaster> villageMasters = (List<VillageMaster>) 
criteria.list();
```